# How to create nested directory in a single command?

Tags: mkdir

Apparently, it's not possible to create a nested directory in a single command?

```
$ sudo mkdir x/y/z
mkdir: cannot create directory 'x/y/z': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 239):

The command you are looking for is `mkdir -p x/y/z`. The `-p` switch create parents directories.

```
~$ mkdir -p d/s/a/e
~$ cd d/s/a/e/
~/d/s/a/e$
```

Answer (score 57):

Use the `-p` option.  Your command should be:

```
sudo mkdir -p x/y/z
```

Comment: This is the best answer.